# Dynamically get field's size in Gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am looking for a way to dynamically get field sizes from GORM models.

An obvious use case, is when you want to validate that the data hold in your object don't exceed the GORM model's definition and hence the DB column size.

```golang
type MyStruct struct {
    field1 string `gorm:"size:10"`
}


func main(){
    s := MyStruct {field1: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"}  // len 26 > 10 
    
    // if len(s.field1) < ...
    db.Create(&s)  // This will panic
}
```

Is there a way to get the value `10` on runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `reflect` package we can!

Docs: https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag

Code with your given example: https://play.golang.org/p/1tmvU2eTkHJ